# Symmetric random variable multiplied by Bernoulli random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

Suppose $X$ is a symmetric random variable in that $X$ and $-X$ have the same distribution. Let $\epsilon$ be a random variable, independent of $X$, with probability $1/2$ of being $1$, and probability $1/2$ of being $-1$. Then does $\epsilon X$ have the same distribution as $X$? If so, how can one show this?

Comment: The answer depends on whether $X$ and $\epsilon$ are independent.

Comment: Think about it.  Why would the answer depend on the independence of these variables?  How would you go about constructing a counterexample if they were **not** independent?  How would you show that two random variables are identically distributed?

Comment: Based on your question history, you should know enough mathematics to understand my comment, be able to formulate an approach, and **elucidate that approach here in your question.**  Only intellectually lazy individuals ask questions without showing evidence of effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Real valued random variables $X$ and $\epsilon X$ will have the same distribution if for every measurable set $A$ that is a subset of the reals, $\mathsf P(X\in A)=\mathsf P(\epsilon X\in A)$.   Which means in essence you must prove that:

$$\forall a\in\Bbb R~:~\mathsf P(X\leq a)=\mathsf P(\epsilon X\leq a)$$

How?   Well, to begin use the law of total probability: $$\mathsf P(\epsilon X\leq a) = \mathsf P(X\leq a,\epsilon=1)+\mathsf P(-X\leq a,\epsilon=-1)$$

Take it from there.

Comment: "Let $ϵ$ be a random variable, independent of $X$, with probability $1/2$ of being $1$, and probability $1/2$ of being $−1$."

Comment: Sorry about that, you're right.